# Does USCF still pay for the FIDE Master application fee?

Tags: fide, uscf, titles

There is not much to add to the question. Quite simply, does USCF still pay for the FIDE Master application fee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Chris Bird, the USCF's "FIDE Events Manager", the USCF only pays for GM, IM, WGM, and WIM titles. FM(WFM) and CM(WCM) are the responsibility of the player. The USCF still applies on your behalf, but you pay the fee.

The fees are currently as follows:

Grandmaster/WGM: 330 Euro

International Master/WIM: 165 Euro

FIDE Master/WFM: 70 Euro

Candidate Master/WCM: 50 Euro

Comment: P.S. To get that information, I emailed him, and he graciously, emailed me back late on a Sunday night, which I was not expecting.